# Why does running SSIS package return permission errors when ran via SSMS on client machine but works OK run from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

When I run the SSIS package via SSMS (right click on package and execute) on the client machine, then I get permission errors at the step where it tries to read an excel file on a shared path. I have full permissions on the shared path.

However, when I run the SSIS package via SSMS (right click on package and execute) on the SQL Server machine, then it runs OK.

What could be possible issues?

Comment: Double Hopping.

Comment: (Not writing this an an answer as it is not my expertise). This is going to be "Double Hopping". This happens when you have 3 (or more hosts) and want them to all use the credentials of the connected user; in this case yours. When you open SSMS on the Instance host, you authenticate to that host, and then that package is run under your credentials. If it needs to communicate to another host, for a file perhaps, your credentials are passed along for authentication, and the file can be accessed.

Comment: When, however, you run the package via SSMS on your local machine you have a "double hop". You Authenticate to your machine. That then passes your credentials to the Server. When it then wants to authenticate to a file path it goes to pass your credentials but it can't (because Kerboros isn't enabled) and so it authenticates **anonymously**. This normally then results in a authentication failure. As i mentioned, however, how you fix this isn't my expertise. Enabling Kerboros falls under network administration.

Comment: Few articles on the subject: [Understanding Kerberos Double Hop](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/understanding-kerberos-double-hop/ba-p/395463), [A brief explanation and solution for the Double Hop problem](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/a-brief-explanation-and-solution-for-the-double-hop-problem)

Answer (score -1):

Probably something with authentication method in your SSIS package connection. If you created the package in server machine and have it as Window Authentication then you can only run it on SQL server machine.

Comment: SSISDB packages can *only* run using Windows Authentication, so I'm not sure of your point here.